# How to get the Download Manager ,download cancel callback? or else how to hide or remove this cancel from notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

When a video is being downloaded there is a cancel option to cancel the download.but when i cancel the download i don't get any callback from DownloadManager to update the app UI.

This cancle option is only available in Android 7 .

Or else is there any option to hide or remove the cancel option from there.

[image]

Comment: Did you find some solution ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

After registering your broadcast receiver for `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`, you can check for DownloadManager status in the onReceive() method of the DownloadManager broadcast as follows -

```
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   checkDownloadStatus();
  } 
 };

private void checkDownloadStatus(){

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
  long id = preferenceManager.getLong(strPref_Download_ID, 0);
  query.setFilterById(id);
  Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
  if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
   int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
   int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
   int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

   switch(status){
   case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
    String failedReason = "";
    switch(reason){
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME:
     failedReason = "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
     failedReason = "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS:
     failedReason = "ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
     failedReason = "ERROR_FILE_ERROR";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR:
     failedReason = "ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE:
     failedReason = "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:
     failedReason = "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
     failedReason = "ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN:
     failedReason = "ERROR_UNKNOWN";
     break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(AndroidDownloadManagerActivity.this, 
      "FAILED: " + failedReason, 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
   case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
    String pausedReason = "";

    switch(reason){
    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI:
     pausedReason = "PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN:
     pausedReason = "PAUSED_UNKNOWN";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK:
     pausedReason = "PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK";
     break;
    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY:
     pausedReason = "PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY";
     break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(AndroidDownloadManagerActivity.this, 
      "PAUSED: " + pausedReason, 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
   case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
    Toast.makeText(AndroidDownloadManagerActivity.this, 
      "PENDING", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
   case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
    Toast.makeText(AndroidDownloadManagerActivity.this, 
      "RUNNING", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    break;
   case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:

    Toast.makeText(AndroidDownloadManagerActivity.this, 
      "SUCCESSFUL", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    downloadManager.remove(id);
    break;
   } 
  } 
 }
```